# Create simplified version of tableau using Google Maps

Tags: google-visualization, tableau-api

Is it possible to create simplified version of Tableau (Just basic visualization) using Google Chart Tools? If so, what are main challenges in imitating Tableau?

What are the advantages of Tableau over Google Chart Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading a bit what Tableau and Google Chart actually does.

**Google Chart** is a library to create visualisations. Basically you need to have your data ready in the correct format and then with the API you can create and customiza a graph to publish on the web.

**Tableau** on the other hand gives you the possibility to directly connect to different data sources, blend and join these sources and then create dashboards that give you an overview of whatever data you would like to view.

So to answer your first question

> Is it possible to create simplified version of Tableau (Just basic visualization) using Google Chart Tools?

Yes it is possible to create basic visualisation with Google Charts (that's what it's made for) but that's also possible with Excel (although that won't give you the interactivity online).

> If so, what are main challenges in imitating Tableau?

You will not be able to join and blend data. You also won't have a fairly easy to understand user interface, since Google Charts is handled on code level. You will also not be able to just "play around" until you see something interesting, at least not as easily as in Tableau

> What are the advantages of Tableau over Google Chart Tools?

that depends on your use case. If you want to get some pretty graphs on your website, Tableau won't be able to do the job and you shoudl use Google Charts.
If you want to have complex, interactive dashboards to examine your data from different sources, you will struggle getting all of that together just with Google Charts and you should probably have a look at Tableau.